# AJAX Parse URL To Pass Variable To MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Have been having trouble passing variables through via a URL to a MySQL query, have read through various solutions here and have tried solving this via AJAX and JQuery but to no avail.

Am populating a list (table) via a MySQL query which produces the link as shown below:

```
echo "<td class='listingTextCentre'><a class='green' href='?sid=".$row[0]."&hid=".$row[1]."'> S".$row[0]."</a></td>";
```

When I hover over the link get the correct values for sid and hid. Am trying to get the sid and hid variables passed via the AJAX below:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({
        url: "srlisting.php",
        type: "get",
        data: {sid: sid, hid: hid},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#divresult').load("srlisting.php");
        },
    });
});
```

However when clicking on the link I receive an error in the console:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for the srlisting.php file:

```
    <?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $sid = $_POST['sid'];

    $rawList = "SELECT * FROM scheds WHERE sched_id = '$sid'";
    $scheduleList = $connection->query($rawList);

    mysql(close); 
    ?>
```

Console outputs are as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

linktest.php:

```
<?php


?> 

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tr><td class='listingTextCentre'><a href='?sid=1&hid=634' class='green'>S1</a></td></tr>
        </table>

<script>

//$("clickme").click(function() {
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    hParts = href.split('&');
    var dataString = '';
    $.each(hParts, function(index,value){
        var vParts = value.split('=');
        dataString += vParts[0] + ':' + vParts[1] + ',';
    });
    sendData = '{' + dataString.slice(0, -1) + '}'; // returns {sid:"$row[0]",hid:"$row[1]"}
    $.ajax ({
        url: "phplinktest.php",
        type: "post",
        data: sendData, // place the string here
        success: function(response) {
            $('#divresult').html(response);
            $('#divresult').show();
        },
    });
});

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

phplinktest.php:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $sid = $_POST['sid'];
    echo $sid;

    var_dump($_POST);         

?>
```

Comment: Try to add the dataType : "JSON"  for you ajax config.
`success: function(response) {
            $('#divresult').load("srlisting.php");
        }, dataType : "JSON"`

Comment: Thanks for that Hugo, but what will this do?

Comment: Note that I have updated my answer with additional information that *all of us* missed in the initial examination of the question while being in a rush to get the data parsed correctly. You should not be using `.load()` in your AJAX function as you are already getting a response form the page in question. See my answer for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: All you need to do now is echo the query results in your PHP. The info echoed will be returned by the AJAX request as setup in my answer.

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, not at this stage, have started a chat with you again.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not where I can do a chat @Wignu. Did you follow my suggestions?

Comment: Ah ok, yes I tried your example in the your blog with the counter and it worked fine. Then I stripped back the link and php files with the error reporting. Getting error "Notice: Undefined index sid in E:\phplinktest.php on line 5. Have put the linktest.php and phplinktest.php code in my original post above.

Comment: Are you running this on a web server?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<td class='listingTextCentre'><a class='green' id='".$row[0]."_".$row[1]."'> S".$row[0]."</a></td>"; ?> 

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
var strid=$(this).attr('id');
strid=strid.split("_");
var sid=strid[0];
var hid=strid[1];
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax ({
    url: "srlisting.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {sid: sid, hid: hid},
    success: function(response) {
        $('#divresult').load("srlisting.php");
    },
});});
```

Comment: Added var sid and that has fixed the ReferenceError thanks. Not sure what you mean by the second part of your answer though.

Comment: I have edited the code , please try the code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I tried that thanks @Amitabh, can see what you've done with splitting the single id into it's components however I've just defined sid and hid with the &(this).attr and that has worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of `sid` and `hid` when you click. That means you're going to have to parse the `href` attribute of the link *which can be done without modifying your markup*:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $('a').attr('href').substring($('a').attr('href').indexOf('?') + 1);
    hParts = href.split('&');
    var dataString = '';
    $.each(hParts, function(index,value){
        var vParts = value.split('=');
        dataString += vParts[0] + ':' + vParts[1] + ',';
    });
    sendData = '{' + dataString.slice(0, -1) + '}'; // returns {sid:"$row[0]",hid:"$row[1]"}
    $.ajax ({
        url: "srlisting.php",
        method: "post",
        data: sendData, // place the string here
        success: function(response) {
            $('#divresult').html(response);
        },
    });
});
```

Parsing the `href` attribute is a little complex, but in the end you get the results you want. The values are parsed and then sent to your PHP script for processing.

1. get the value of the `href` attribute, [**minus the starting `?`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
2. [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the `&`
3. [**loop through**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), splitting each remaining string to get the variable name and value

   1. concatenate the variable names and values together in a way that they can be used in a post string
4. finish up by adding the brackets and [**removing the last `,`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from your string

**EDIT**:

Finally, you're trying to use the `.load()` function to place the data returned from AJAX into the `div`. `.load()` is essentially another AJAX call which is not needed and in fact should not be used. You should just set the HTML in the `div` to be the response of your AJAX call:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#divresult').html(response);
},
```

**EDIT** made a change to get the proper substring from the `href` in the link, regardless of how it is configured as long as the `href` is a proper query string.

Comment: Thank you for posting that Jay, I have added it and can see the parameters being passed in the console. Now I just have to get the query to run and populate the div :).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Jay that is now working as I intended. Just one last question (hopefully) and that is how do I actually use the value in srlisting.php - this is a purely php file (no html) that runs two queries based on the values of sid and hid. I've tried $sid = $_POST['sid']; however it doesn't pass the variable through.

Comment: Edit your original post to show your PHP and we should be able to work it out.

Comment: Hi Jay I've added the php code for srlisting, it's a very basic MySQL query, what I need to do is extract the sid and hid values from sendData but I'm unsure how to do so.

Comment: Note that I have changed the method to "post", making the variables available in the POST array in PHP @Wignu

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm picking all you have done was change the method to post? I've done that but still getting no value when echoing sid . Have following code: echo "sid: ".$sid."<br />"; - just gives sid and no value.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console @Wignu?

Comment: Hi Jay, the response given is - sid: <br />hid: <br />. Post is - parameters; {rlisting.php?sid:1,hid:6... Source; {rlisting.php?sid:1,hid:634}

Comment: @Wignu did you get this all sorted out?

Comment: Unfortunately still haven't got it resolved, I just can't figure out how to get the values for sid and hid into the query.

Comment: Are the values not in the `$_POST` array? Can you add `var_dump($_POST)` to the top of your PHP page and put the output here @Wignu? Are you able to get [a basic AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) query working?

Comment: The var dump gives array(0) { }. I would've guessed the Ajax is working as the parameter given is {  rlisting.php?sid:1,hid:6... which is the url converted to the sendData string.

Comment: If the `var_dump()` is empty *no* POST variables are arriving at the PHP script. Try `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: Same empty var_dump(). I'm going back and re-checking my code to make sure I haven't inadvertently changed something I shouldn't have.

Comment: Checked everything. Am getting the following under POST: Parameters {sid:1,hid:234}; JSON sid     1  hid    234   ; Source {sid:1, hid:234} if that's any help?

Comment: Anything in `var_dump()`?

Comment: No, that's still giving array(0) {}. Should I move this to a chat as it's getting a bit long?

Comment: Sure, that'll be fine although I may have to handle work issues too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98608/discussion-between-wignu-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: Hi Jay, did you see the error report I put  in the comments of my original post? I searched to find the solution butwas unable to get it working.

Comment: Hi Jay, it's running on Uniserv Winamp server at the moment.

Comment: Hi Jay, realise it's a crazy trime etc but do you have any further ideas on what the problem may be?